# AMD Drivers for HD4890 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have Ubuntu 15.04, I need someone to explain me how to install amd drivers for my graphic card on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: what does `lspci` say?

Comment: `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV790 [Radeon HD 4890]` (I can't copy all)
'

Comment: AMD dropped support for HD4000, [that was](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_catalyst_legacy2&num=1) in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no proprietary drivers for this GPU. Open drivers are already installed.
So there is nothing to install.

Comment: So games will work without installing drivers?

Comment: I can't guarantee that all games will work, but most of them should work.  Anyway there is no option.

Comment: CS:GO is working and Minecraft too, that's good enough for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to your problem could be

- Open the System Settings
- Select Software& Updates
  From the new Popped-Up window, Select Additional Drivers and hopefully your system will recognize the required drivers.

[image]

Good Luck!

Comment: It shows this: http://shrani.si/f/1m/12x/22zU4YUM/selection001.png

Comment: what happens when you choose the device and click on Apply? Also is it plugged in properly and you have any Monitor Output going from it?

Comment: As I said, there are no proprietary drivers for that card. If anything appears in this window, it is not good to install it. You will have blackscreen on boot.