# Problem with AMD Graphic cards on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics, fan

I have ubuntu 17.04 installed, and my screen resolution is too low and i can't find the proper resolution in "Display settings" section; Also my graphic card's fan makes a loud noise, i mean ubuntu can't control the fan speed,
I did some researches but seems like there is no driver available for my graphic card on ubuntu 17 or even on ubuntu 16, i tried installing `catalyst` and `catalyst-legacy` but it just kills the display and it shows only a black screen with nothing in it.
What should i do to get ubuntu work with my graphic card? :(

**System information :**

- Ubuntu 17.04 ( latest )
- Memory : `4GB`
- Graphic card: `AMD, ATI RV790( Radeon HD 4890 )`
- Screen resolution: `1366x768` ( but it gives me max. 1024x768 in the installed ubuntu )
- CPU : `Intel Xeon ( 4cores , 2.6GHZ, 12MB L2 cache )`

Comment: There is nothing to do. Only an opensource driver can be used. Ubuntu doesn't control fan speed as any OS doesn't. The fan speed is high because the GPU is loaded by 3D effects. You an install Xubuntu on this hardware that does not have these 3D effects.

Comment: @Pilot6 fan speed is strangely high, in Windows version of catalyst driver you can manually or autamatically control fan speed, i actually have both Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed on my system, but, it works fine in windows with no weird loud fan voice or wrong resolution

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/620149/630638 This thread might be of some help.

Comment: @GurdeepMundi Unfortunately, it doesn't work me :(